# jQuery Flot: 24 hour axis

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm using [jQuery Flot plugin](https://github.com/flot/flot) and I would like to have 24 hour x-axis. But how to accomplish that? I included necessary time plugin (jquery.flot.time.js) and tried something like this:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%H",
    tickSize: [1, "day"],
    twelveHourClock: true
}
```

but nothing is showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by a "24 hour x-axis"?  One that is limited to just 24 hours?  How would the ticks be labeled, etc...?

Comment: I want to have on x-asix time every 1 hour (24-hour clock), like this: 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 etc.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use tickSize: [1, "hour"] instead of "day"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%I:%M %p", // HH:MM am/pm
    tickSize: [1, "hour"], // tick every hour
    twelveHourClock: true,
    min: 1390780800000, // start of today
    max: 1390863600000 // end of today
},
```

Very contrived example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv958/1/).

[image]

**EDITS**

To show last 24 hours use:

```
var epochT = (new Date).getTime(); // time right now in js epoch

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], {
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%I:%M %p",
    tickSize: [1, "hour"],
    twelveHourClock: true,
    min: epochT - 86400000, // time right now - 24 hours ago in milliseonds
    max: epochT,
    timezone: "browser" // switch to using local time on plot
},
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv958/2/).

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :). Have only one question, what exactly means those numbers min/max and is possible in max to have current hour?

Comment: @CookieMan, Those min/max values are javascript epoch times for the beginning and end of today.  See edits for your other question.

Comment: could you help me please in this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349545/flot-jquery-is-it-possible-to-draw-this-kind-of-chart